# how to make dictionary from given list of dictionary

Tags: python

I have a list of dictionary like below:

```
targer = [
    {"id":1,"search":"xyz"},
    {"id":2,"children":[
        {"id":3,"search":'xyz'},
        {"id":4,"search":'xyz'},
        {"id":5,"children":[
            {"id":6,"search":'xyz'},
            {"id":7,"search":'xyz'},
            {"id":8,"search":'xyz'}]},
        {"id":9,"search":'xyz'},
        {"id":10,"search":'xyz'}]},
    {"id":11},{"id":12}]
```

Now i want to make a list of dictionary like below from target list:

```
output = [
    {'tier1': 1, 'searchterm': 'xyz'},
    {'tier1': 2, 'tier2': 3,'searchterm': 'xyz'},
    {'tier1': 2,'tier2': 4,'searchterm': 'xyz'},
    {'tier1': 2, 'tier2': 5,'tier3': 6,'searchterm': 'xyz'},
    {'tier1': 2, 'tier2': 5,'tier3': 7,'searchterm': 'xyz'},
    {'tier1': 2, 'tier2': 5,'tier3': 8, 'searchterm': 'xyz'},
    {'tier1': 2, 'tier2': 9,'searchterm': 'xyz'},
    {'tier1': 2, 'tier2': 10,'searchterm': 'xyz'},
    {'tier1': 11, 'searchterm': 'xyz'},
    {'tier1': 12, 'searchterm': 'xyz'}]
```

I tried some steps:
1.first i convert target list in to list like below:

```
mylist = [
    [1, 'xyz'],
    [2, 3, 'xyz'],
    [2, 4, 'xyz'],
    [2, 5, 6, 'xyz'],
    [2, 5, 7, 'xyz'],
    [2, 5, 8, 'xyz'],
    [2, 9, 'xyz'],
    [2, 10, 'xyz'],
    [11],
    [12]]
```

2.then i applied below code on mylist to get output:

```
for i in lis:
dic={}


length=len(i)
if length==2:

    dic['tier1']=i[0]
    dic['searchterm']=i[1]

if length==3:
    dic['tier1']=i[0]
    dic['tier2']=i[1]
    dic['searchterm']=i[2]

if length==4:
    dic['tier1']=i[0]
    dic['tier2']=i[1]
    dic['tier3']=i[2]
    dic['searchterm']=i[3]

if length==5:
    dic['tier1']=i[0]
    dic['tier2']=i[1]
    dic['tier3']=i[2]
    dic['tier4']=i[3]
    dic['searchterm']=i[4]

if length==6:
    dic['tier1']=i[0]
    dic['tier2']=i[1]
    dic['tier3']=i[2]
    dic['tier4']=i[3]
    dic['tier5']=i[4]
    dic['searchterm']=i[5]

target.append(dic)
```

But i want to output from direct target list with out applying above steps.
Please help to solve this problem.

Comment: Why is the `searchterm` value for `tier1:11` and `tier1:12` "xyz"? In the original data structure, those dictionaries do not have `search` keys.

Answer (score 1):

recursive generator will do the trick:

```
def flatten(list_of_dicts, tier = 1, prev = {}):

    for item in list_of_dicts:
        curr = prev.copy()
        curr['tier%d' %tier] = item['id']
        if 'children' in item:
            for next in flatten(item['children'], tier + 1, curr): 
                yield next
        else:
            if 'search' in item: #some items don't have it
                curr['searchterm'] = item['search']
            yield curr


>>> list(flatten(targer))
[{'tier1': 1, 'searchterm': 'xyz'}, {'tier1': 2, 'searchterm': 'xyz', 'tier2': 3}, {'tier1': 2, 'searchterm': 'xyz', 'tier2': 4}, {'tier1': 2, 'searchterm': 'xyz', 'tier3': 6, 'tier2': 5}, {'tier1': 2, 'searchterm': 'xyz', 'tier3': 7, 'tier2': 5}, {'tier1': 2, 'searchterm': 'xyz', 'tier3': 8, 'tier2': 5}, {'tier1': 2, 'searchterm': 'xyz', 'tier2': 9}, {'tier1': 2, 'searchterm': 'xyz', 'tier2': 10}, {'tier1': 11}, {'tier1': 12}]
```